# How can i remove LibreOffice from ppa, then install from regular repos?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, libreoffice, ppa

Using Ubuntu 18.04 up to date.

Have had LibreOffice intalled on this machine for a couple years using LibreOffice's ppa to have the latest version installed.

2-3 days ago the latest LibreOffice update showed up and proceeded to update as usual, only this one time... ended up broken.

While trying to update it always end up displaying this error message after aborting the operation:

```
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/modules/smath/menubar/menubar.xml', which is also in package libreoffice-common 1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1
```

Tried with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
```

and also:

```
sudo apt-get remove fonts-opensymbol libreoffice libreoffice-* openoffice.org-dtd-officedocument1.0 python*-uno uno-libs3-* ure ure-dbg
```

But didn't fix anything.

Tried with synaptic afterwards which identifies 21 broken packages, tried to fix 'em through synaptic but at some point aborts and displays the following error message:

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-math_1%3a6.4.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/modules/smath/menubar/menubar.xml', which is also in package libreoffice-common 1:6.3.5~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1

W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:5

W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:5

W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:5

W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:5

W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:5

W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:5

W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:5

W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:5

W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:5

W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:5

W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:5
```

Right now i'd like to completely remove LibreOffice, remove LibreOffice's ppa and then install LibreOffice from "regular" Bionic repos.

Where should i start ?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Thought i had to remove files first, then remove ppa, but managed to remove this ppa combining those lines somehow... and then removing it through synaptic ( it still was on the ppa list ) . After that... all those files were finally gone, now i just reinstalled LibreOffice again ( Flathub version ) & working already. Thanks again !!